# Delete every number that comes before "="

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

i have a very, very, very long list. Like over 830,000 characters. I will of course perform said command on a copy.

There are multiple lines, like this

```
hey1=lol
hey2=lol
hey3=lol
```

I want that to turn out like this

```
hey=lol
hey=lol
hey=lol
```

This must be possible with sed, awk or similar?

The reason im not using Sumblime text is because all lines do not have a number before them.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html):

```
sed -e 's/[0-9]*=/=/' < data
```

This replaces ([`s`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_03)) any text that is [zero or more characters in the range `0-9`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) followed by an `=` sign with just the `=` sign.

Comment: `s/[0-9]+=/=/` might be easier to mentally map to the OP's request, but either should work just as well. Also, I'd probably redirect the output to a file too. :) Even so, +1.

Comment: `+` is [annoyingly non-standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_03).

Comment: just for completeness' sake you can also use [:digit:] as in `sed -e 's/[:digit:]*.=/=/g' < data`

Comment: @Dani_l, you have to put the character class inside brackets: `s/[[:digit:]]*=/=/`

Comment: @glennjackman did you try my solution? both work. Don't forget the period "." after the star "*".

Comment: Your regex matches this: **zero** or more of (`:` or `d` or `i` or `g` or `t`) followed by any character (`.`) followed by `=`. If the data were to have the line `hey12=foo`, you would output `hey1=foo`. If there data contains `hey1234:::::::::tgidX=foo`, you would output `hey1234=foo`. So yes, your solution fits the sample data, but only by chance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove every number that comes before '='

```
awk -F= '{gsub(/[[:digit:]]/, X, $1)}1' OFS== file
```

Above code satisfies even if there multiple numbers scattered before '='

```
hey1=lol
h9e7y2=lol
1hey3=lol
```